# problem in not showing the statement after arrow inside if else statement

Tags: latex, overleaf

I have written an algorithm in latex like the following.

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algorithm}\label{euclid}
    ...
    \State $\vec{cle} \gets $\text{Mean($o1,o2$)}
                \If{$\vec{clh[t]}$ is empty}
                     \State $\vec{clh[t]} \gets $\vec{cle}$
                \Else
                     \State $\vec{$clh[t]} \gets \text{MeanCalc}($\vec{$cle}*0.1,clh[t]*0.5)$
                \EndIf
            \EndIf
```

My problem is, in the line after If statement, $\vec{cle}$ doesn't show up after arrow. Also after else, \State $\vec{$clh[t]} doesn't show up before arrow. I appreciate if anyone can help me with this

Comment: Please provide your compiled output... I would like to verify something.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the math environment `$...$` in your snippet was inconsistent ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My Algorithm}\label{alg:euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}

\State $\vec{cle} \gets $\text{Mean($o1,o2$)}
    \If{$\vec{clh[t]}$ is empty}
        \State $\vec{clh[t]} \gets \vec{cle}$
    \Else
        \State $\vec{clh[t]} \gets $\text{MeanCalc}($\vec{cle}*0.1,clh[t]*0.5)$  
    \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

With the result:
[image]

Hope this helps